# Displaying an Image from a file in an Image control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a huge amount of images (10000 +) all of which I know are JPEGS (from the file header of FF D8)

basically I search a database which gives me matching filenames for the search. I then want to show these images in a list view.

my problem is that none of the images have extensions and when I try to load the image into the list view I get the following error:

```
No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found
```

I believe this is because it cant determine the file type to open it.

I am attempting to bind to a path property using a value converter to return the BitmapImage which will be displayed in the list view Image control.

the converter is here:

```
public class PathToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (File.Exists(value.ToString()))
            {
                //these files are JPEGs but without an extension
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString()));
            }
            else return new BitmapImage();

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

The WPF control in XAML is here:

```
   <!--  The list view containing the images, bound to the logos collection in the background  -->
        <ListView x:Name="lstImages"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Shoeprints}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedImageIndex}">

            <!--  Use a wrap panel so that the images appear side by side instead of one in each row  -->
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <!--  Sets the template for the data to be displayed  -->
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--  Defines the actual image being displayed  -->
                    <Image Width="50"
                        Height="50"
                        Margin="5"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Source="{Binding ShoePrintImagePath, Converter={StaticResource PathToImageSourceConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

and ShoePrintImagePath is a string property in the ShoePrints class. I know that the rest of this works as I have successfully bound to other properties in this class in this list vew but I cant work this out for images.

C#
VS 2012
WPF
Xaml

Comment: Just a note: Your assumption about the missing file extension is wrong - a perfectly valid image file in a supported image format is also understood and read just fine even if the file name is lacking or having an incorrect file extension. Your problem is not related to the file extension. What the error message is hinting at is that you perhaps have some files in an image format for which .NET/WPF does not provide "in-house" support

Comment: If you step-through the converter, does it confirm that the file exists?

Comment: Yes it does, the file exists, if I drag and drop it into paint, or manually add the extension .jpg then it works fine

Comment: Also. you can use the `return Binding.DoNothing`, to avoid using resources on empty Bitmap instances.

Comment: I've just tried with a test application with a png image (without .png). The image was loaded and shown. Have you tried changing the `UriKind`?

Comment: try changing `return new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString()));` to `var image = new BitmapImage(newUri(value.ToString())); return image;` and set a breakpoint. Is the image created? 
Just to verify, that everything up to creating the image is working.